# jquery not working on netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: jquery, performance

jquery doesn't seem to be working on my `netbeans 8.0.2`. the div where the pictures are supposed to be sliding either doesn't  show, or it does , but without the pictures. But when i run same code from notepad, it runs without any issues.

here is a sample of my code
my java versions are : `jsf 2.2`and `jdk 1.0.8_25`. using Glassfish server 4.1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({

            animation: "slide"
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
   <div class="flexslider" style="background-position: center center; width: auto; height: 250px; position: relative; background-color: #304179; text-align: center;">
   <ul class="slides">
     <li><img src="igbo.jpg" width="150px" height="250px" /></li>
     <li><img src="guy.jpg" width="350px" height="250px" /></li>
     <li><img src="Bule.jpg" width="350px" height="250px" /></li>
     <li><img src="guy.jpg" width="350px" height="250px" /></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should add the relevant code and specify your local setup. It may be a simple reference to the jquery lib.

Comment: how do mean specifying local setup?. all the links were properly referenced. the same code worked from elsewhere(notepad)

Comment: Netbeans can be messing up with those links, I don´t use netbeans, but I know it can  reference css and js differently than plain html in a browser. With setup I mean what kind of project are you using in netbeans.

Comment: java web. im trying to develop a web app using jsf

Comment: When asking for help it is particularly helpful to give us as many details as possible.  Notepad and Netbeans are editors, and as such you aren't particularly 'running' any code from within them.   Showing us the code and describing your problems in as much depth as you can will help the community to assist you properly, and provide you with better answers.

Comment: Can you post the jsf page code as an edit to your question? Please specify which version of java and jsf you are using. And what server you are using?

Comment: Use something like Developer Tools for chrome (F12) or FireBug for firefox to determine if all your resources are loading correctly. The Network tab for these tools will highlite any missing resources due to incorrect paths.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured this out. You have to tell the webpage that you want to use jQuery and where it should get it. You can either put the latest jQuery file in on your server or link to it. Here is how i did it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I simply downloaded jQuery from http://jquery.com/download/
Simply edit this so your path to the file is correct, and it should work :) Mine did!

It also works directly from the web by putting the link, like so:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

Source: Codecademy